# Entity Framework Add-Migration Ignores FSharpOption properties

Tags: entity-framework, f#, c#-to-f#

I am trying to convert a C# project into F#. The C# project uses Entity Framework as the primary means of data access.

I have the following interface in F#:

```
type public IFoo =
    abstract member Bar : DateTime option
```

Which is implemented by the following C# class:

```
public class Foo : IFoo
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public FSharpOption<DateTime> Bar { get; set; }
}
```

(I'm doing the conversion one piece at a time, so the interface is already in F# but the class is still in C#.)

When I run `Add-Migration`, the `Bar` property gets ignored.

The solution I currently have is to just change the interface signature of the `Bar` property to `Nullable<DateTime>`. But I believe that would prevent me from working with the interface using "idiomatic" F#.

What other alternatives do I have? Thanks in advance.